# Vagrant puppet provision fail with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, vagrant, provisioning, puppet

I am trying to set up vagrant with GAE. I've got the VM up and running fine, but get a fail when using puppet. Here is my command output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'precise32'...

[0K[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
```

this continues fine until it tries to install GAE and fails:

```
[0;37mdebug: Exec[download-sdk](provider=posix): Executing '/usr/bin/wget -O /var/tmp/google_appengine_1.8.1.zip http://googleappengine.googlecode
.com/files/google_appengine_1.8.1.zip'[0m
[0;37mdebug: Executing '/usr/bin/wget -O /var/tmp/google_appengine_1.8.1.zip http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.8.1.zi
p'[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Exec[download-sdk]/returns: executed successfully[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Exec[download-sdk]: The container Class[Google_appengine] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;37mdebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/dpkg-query -W --showformat ${Status} ${Package} ${Version}\n python-markupsaf
e'[0m
[0;37mdebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install python-markupsafe'[
0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Package[python-markupsafe]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Package[python-markupsafe]: The container Class[Google_appengine] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Grunt/File[/usr/bin/grunt-compile]/ensure: created[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Grunt/File[/usr/bin/grunt-compile]: The container Class[Grunt] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Schedule[never]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;37mdebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/dpkg-query -W --showformat ${Status} ${Package} ${Version}\n expect'[0m
[0;37mdebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install expect'[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Package[expect]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Package[expect]: The container Class[Google_appengine] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;37mdebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/dpkg-query -W --showformat ${Status} ${Package} ${Version}\n unzip'[0m
[0;37mdebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install unzip'[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Package[unzip]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Package[unzip]: The container Class[Google_appengine] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;37mdebug: Exec[extract-sdk](provider=posix): Executing '/usr/bin/unzip /var/tmp/google_appengine_1.8.1.zip -d /opt/google_appengine/1.8.1'[0m
[0;37mdebug: Executing '/usr/bin/unzip /var/tmp/google_appengine_1.8.1.zip -d /opt/google_appengine/1.8.1'[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Exec[extract-sdk]/returns: executed successfully[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Exec[extract-sdk]: The container Class[Google_appengine] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/opt/google_appengine/current]/ensure: created[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/opt/google_appengine/current]: The container Class[Google_appengine] will propagate my refresh ev
ent[0m
[0;37mdebug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderUpstart: Executing '/sbin/status google-appengine-server'[0m
[1;35merr: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/Service[google-appengine-server]: Could not evaluate: Execution of '/sbin/status google-appengine-server'
 returned 1: status: Unknown job: google-appengine-server
[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-update]: Dependency Service[google-appengine-server] has failures: true[0m
[0;33mwarning: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-update]: Skipping because of failed dependencies[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-rollback]: Dependency Service[google-appengine-server] has failures: true[0m
[0;33mwarning: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-rollback]: Skipping because of failed dependencies[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-shell]: Dependency Service[google-appengine-server] has failures: true[0m
[0;33mwarning: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-shell]: Skipping because of failed dependencies[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-appcfg]: Dependency Service[google-appengine-server] has failures: true[0m
[0;33mwarning: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-appcfg]: Skipping because of failed dependencies[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Grunt/File[/usr/bin/grunt-watch]/ensure: created[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Grunt/File[/usr/bin/grunt-watch]: The container Class[Grunt] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;37mdebug: Class[Grunt]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Schedule[weekly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;37mdebug: /Schedule[puppet]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-log]: Dependency Service[google-appengine-server] has failures: true[0m
[0;33mwarning: /Stage[main]/Google_appengine/File[/usr/bin/gae-log]: Skipping because of failed dependencies[0m
[0;37mdebug: Class[Google_appengine]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;37mdebug: Finishing transaction -614701298[0m
[0;37mdebug: Storing state[0m
[0;32minfo: Creating state file /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml[0m
[0;37mdebug: Stored state in 0.00 seconds[0m
[0;36mnotice: Finished catalog run in 91.19 seconds[0m
[0;37mdebug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]/ensure: created[0m
[0;37mdebug: Finishing transaction -614350728[0m
[0;37mdebug: Received report to process from precise32[0m
[0;37mdebug: Processing report from precise32 with processor Puppet::Reports::Store[0m
vagrant : The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
At line:1 char:1
+ vagrant up
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The following S...ro exit status.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
puppet apply --verbose --debug --modulepath '/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' --detailed-exitcodes 
/tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the content of your Puppet manifest?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like when puppet tries to run '/sbin/status google-appengine-server' it fails. I don't see anywhere when the module tries to put in an upstart job for google-appengine-server so this could be the issue.

I'd try to look around for resources which install google packages or that run install scripts from the sdk or that involve adding a file called /etc/init.d/google-appengine-server and try to set up some ordering between the exec which fails and that resource.